# Change loss function to always contain whole object in tensorflow object-detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on number detector and use object-detection API from tensorflow. Sometimes the predicted bounding box does not contain whole number, which cannot be read then. I would like to change the loss function to penalize much more when part of a number is missing then when the predicted bounding box is too large.

I found definition of IOU in the file *utils/np_box_ops.py*, but it is probably not used during training. Where can I find implemantation of loss function used during training?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have in mind that there might be a problem with your dataset and/or the model/config you are using that we can't be aware because you didn't share any information about those things.

With that said, the avaliable loss functions are defined in:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/losses.py

With corresponding .proto definitions for your config file in:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/losses.proto

You might be interested in trying `WeightedIOULocalizationLoss`.

You can also try to adjust the parameter `localization_weight` in the loss section of your config file:

```
loss {
  classification_loss {
    weighted_sigmoid {
    }
  }
  localization_loss {
    weighted_smooth_l1 {
    }
  }
  hard_example_miner {
    num_hard_examples: 3000
    iou_threshold: 0.99
    loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
    max_negatives_per_positive: 3
    min_negatives_per_image: 0
  }
  classification_weight: 1.0
  localization_weight: 1.0
}
```

And, as a little hack, you could try to post-process the predicted boxes by adding a little offset.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer.  I use model as it gives better performace. I think it doesnt support different loss function than WeightedSmoothL1LocalizationLoss. I cant figure out, how it works. Specifically i dont understand the format of prediction_tensor and target_tensor. I When I print it i get: `prediction
[[[0.157295913 1.6302464 -2.796139 -3.47752237][2.89026403 1.98689461 -2.25848556 -0.561769187][1.54640901 2....`  The 4-tuples might be bounding boxes, but i dont understand the negative values.